# How to distinguish AVAudioSession interruptions between recording and playing

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudiosession

I am using AVAudioSession to do audio playing and recording.It seems that both way register the same interruption notification.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self selector:@selector(handleInterruption:) name:AVAudioSessionInterruptionNotification object: [AVAudioSession 
sharedInstance]];
```

My question is how to recognize which way the interruption happens.I need to know it to inform my web page;

Answer (score 0):

The notification handler gets the notification as argument. The notification holds it "sender" in the property `object`. This is the audio session.